# Configure git in bash script if user.name contains spaces

Tags: git, bash, shell, environment-variables, sh

I am writing a script to set-up the environment and I want to be possible to configure git with the new name, email and github acc. The new values I am passing with options -n -e -g respectively as in the script below.

Unfortunately, if the user.name contains spaces the `$git_name` variable is referring only to the first part of it. Is there a way to do this correctly and clean?

```
#!/bin/bash

git_github=`git config --global --get-all  user.github`
git_email=`git config --global --get-all  user.email`
git_name="$(git config --global --get-all user.name)" 
echo "Before:" $git_github $git_email $git_name

while getopts :g:e:n: option
do
    case "${option}"
    in
    g) git config --global user.github ${OPTARG};;
    e) git config --global user.email ${OPTARG};;
    n) git config --global user.name ${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

git_github=`git config --get user.github`
git_email=`git config --get user.email`
git_name=`git config --get-all user.name`
echo "After:" $git_github $git_email $git_name
```

Answer (score 3):

The command needs the name to be encapsulated into the brackets, so the solution would be:

```
git config --global user.name "\"${OPTARG}\""
```